# Open Neighborhood of Closed Set

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Consider $A$ to be a closed (compact and convex if needed) subset of metric space $(\mathbb{R}^n, d)$, then for any open neighborhood $M$ of $A$ ($A \subseteq M$), there exists a $\delta>0$ such that $A_\delta \subseteq M$ where $A_\delta = \bigcup_{\mathbf{x} \in A} B_\delta (\mathbf{x})$.

The statement holds intuitively true for me. But I am having trouble rigorously prove the statement above.

I am aware that since $M$ is open and $A \subseteq M$, by definition of open set, I can say that $\forall~\mathbf{x} \in A$, there exists a $\delta(\mathbf{x})>0$ such that $B_{\delta(\mathbf{x})} \mathbf{x} \subseteq M$. But in my question, $\delta$ is constant with respect to $\mathbf{x} \in A$.

I have been struggling on this for a while now, any help or hints would be much appreciated.

Comment: Compactness is needed. Consider $A = \{(x,0) \in \mathbb{R}^2\}$, $M = \left\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2: |y| < \frac{1}{1+x^2}\right\}$

Comment: Hint, given compact $A$: Consider a sequence $\delta_n$ approaching zero, and a sequence $x_n$ in $A$ where $B_{\delta_n}(x_n) \nsubseteq M$.

Comment: Alternatively, consider that $\sup\{\delta>0\mid B_\delta(x)\subseteq M\}$ is a continuous function of $x$ and thus has a minimum on $A$ if $A$ is compact.

Comment: As yet another approach for compact $A$, for each $x \in A$, choose a $\delta_x > 0$ such that $B_{\delta_x}(x) \subseteq M$, and choose a finite subcover $\{ B_{\delta_{x_i}}(x_i) \mid i \in I \}$.  Then $\delta := \frac{1}{2} \min_{i \in I} \delta_{x_i}$ will work.

Comment: @aschepler Could you elaborate a bit more on the hint? I think your counter example makes sense to me. In that counter example, there will be no constant $\delta > 0$ such that $A_\delta \subseteq M$.

Comment: @DanielSchepler Thank you for your hints. I think it makes sense.

Comment: @DanielSchepler Could you check if I prove this correctly? For any open neighborhood $M$ of $A$, $\forall~x \in A$, there exists a $\delta_x>0$ such that $B_{\delta_x} (x) \subseteq M$. Therefore, for all open $M$ of $A$, there exists an open covering $\bigcup_{x \in A} B_{\delta_{x}} (x) \subseteq M$. Since $A$ is compact, there exists a finite subcovering such that $A \subseteq \bigcup_{i\in I} B_{\delta_{x_i}} (x_i) \subseteq \bigcup_{x \in A} B_{\delta_{x}} (x) \subseteq M$. Let $\delta=\frac1 2 \min_{i \in I} (\delta_{x_i})$, $A_\delta \subseteq M$.

Comment: That's the idea.  But on thinking about it more, I'm not convinced that what I wrote is right.  Maybe what you have to do is: first, find a radius for each point, then shrink the radius at each point by a factor of 2, *then* find a subcover, then set $\delta$ to the minimum shrunk radius.

Comment: @DanielSchepler I don't think the idea you provided will work. Since $\delta$ is taken in the finite subcovering, it is possible there is a $\delta_x < \delta$ in the open covering $\{B_{\delta_x} (x)\}_{x\in A}$. This won't ensure that $A_\delta \subseteq M$ even if I shrink the radius $\delta_x$ and then take $\delta$.

Comment: @DerekPan Yes, I saw the same issue, hence my last previous comment.  If you follow those updates:: for each $x \in A$ find $\delta_x$ with $B_{\delta_x}(x)\subseteq M$.  Then $\{B_{\frac{1}{2}\delta_x}(x)\}$ covers $A$, so find a finite subcover $\{B_{\frac{1}{2}\delta_{x_i}}(x_i)\mid i\in I \}$ and set $\delta:=\min_{i\in I}(\frac{1}{2}\delta_{x_i})$.   Then if you have $x \in A$, there is some $x_i$ within $\delta$ of $x$; and then, since $\delta \le \frac{1}{2} \delta_{x_i}$, you have $B_\delta(x) \subseteq B_{2\delta}(x_i) \subseteq B_{\delta_{x_i}}(x_i) \subseteq M$.

Comment: @DanielSchepler Oh, I see. So the trick is mainly after the part "Then if you have $x \in A$, ...."? I believe you used the symmetry of metric to claim that for all $x \in A$, there exists some $x_i$ such that $x_i \in B_\delta(x)$. Then, I guess you can use triangle inequality to show $B_\delta(x) \subseteq B_{2\delta}(x)$? The rest will follow by the construction of the finite subcovering?

Comment: Yes, that's it exactly.

Comment: @DanielSchepler Thank you for making this clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As indicated in the comments, compactness of $A$ is needed.  Now, assuming that $A$ is compact, for each $x \in A$ you can find $\delta_x$ such that $B_{\delta_x}(x) \subseteq M$.  Now observe that $\{ B_{\delta_x / 2}(x) \mid x \in A \}$ covers $A$, so there exists a finite subcover $\{ B_{\delta_{x_i} / 2}(x_i) \mid i \in I \}$.  We now set $\delta := \min_{i\in I} (\delta_{x_i} / 2)$.

Now suppose that $x \in A$.  Then $x \in B_{\delta_{x_i / 2}}(x_i)$ for some $i \in I$.  Therefore,
$$B_\delta(x) \subseteq B_{d(x, x_i) + \delta}(x_i) \subseteq B_{\delta_{x_i}}(x_i) \subseteq M.$$
Here, we used that $d(x, x_i) < \delta_{x_i} / 2$, and also $\delta \le \delta_{x_i} / 2$, so $d(x, x_i) + \delta < \delta_{x_i}$.

Answer (score 1):

As in the comment you can see that compactness is needed.
If you assume that $A$ is compact, then you can consider the map $f:A\to \Bbb R$ given by $$ f(x)=d(x, \Bbb R^n\setminus M)$$ for every $x\in A$. Since $A$ is compact, $f$ is continuous and $A\subset M$ then $f$ admits a positive global minimum , that is there exists $\delta>0$ such that $B(x,\delta)\subset M$ for every $x\in A$.